# Accessing VxWorks Target Shell

Tags: vxworks, rtos

I want to ask a question related to Tornado/VxWorks 5.4

I would like to to access VxWorks **target shell** which is running under my embedded switch. I am using Tornado with VxWorks 5.4 kernel. In Tornado there is a WindSh (**Host Shell**) which I can access directly from Tornado IDE itself. However my question is how can I access target shell? In some sites they say that can be done through serial port, however there is not a serial interface directly into my embedded device. I also tried to do it via telnet or FTP but it also did not work. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you for your answers in advance.

Regards,

Alper

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify some things:
The host shell runs on your development station and communicates with the Debug Agent on your target board (presumably via ethernet).  It sends command to the debug agent to fetch information or set breakpoints.  But all the parsing is done on the host.

The target shell exists as a task that communicates with some kind of hardware interface and the parsing is done by the target with the help of a local symbol file.

In order for the target shell to be present, it has to be configured in your vxworks kernel. Do you know if this is the case?  You can't talk to a target shell if it's not compiled in...

The vast majority of target shells use a serial port for their I/O.
I know that vxWorks 5.5 could be configured to redirect the shell I/O to a telnet port. However, again, this has to be configured in the kernel.  This is typically NOT be the standard configuration on target boards.

Answer (score 0):

The target shell is optional, you have to select it in target configuration.  Once you have done that it will work over stdin/stdout (typically a serial port, but may be an integrated display and keyboard if your hardware and BSP support it), or Telnet, but again only if it is configured that way.